# Simulate login without database using Ajax and XML

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction, I would like to simulate authenticating a login using XML data instead of a database (it's for a college project). I am not sure how to do this and I can only find tutorials on writing to HTML from an XML/JSON file, not verifying data. Below is my jQuery Ajax so far:

```
$( ".register-form" ).submit(function() {

var $username = $('username');
var $email = $('email');
var $password = $('password');

$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: '../assets/data/login.xml',
 data: loginForm,
 dataType: "xml",
 success: function(xmlData){

  $(xmlData).find('login').each(function(){ 

    if($("#signin-email") === $email) {
      console.log("it works!");
    }

    else {
      console.log("not working");
    }


  });
},

  }); //end of ajax call
});
```

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<!-- list of usernames, emails and passwords available  -->

<loginForm> 

  <login>
    <username>admin</username>
    <email>admin@example.com</email>
    <password>password</password>
  </login>  

  <login>
    <username>dara</username>
    <email>dara@gmail.com</email>
    <password>password</password>
  </login>  

</loginForm>
```

Basically I want to allow users to log in if they use the right information, for instance, if they use "admin" or "dara" as their username with the corresponding password, and give an error if they use anything else. If anyone has any advice I'd really appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to do the authentication part in the client, by send it all the logins available to the site -- that is definitely a **BAD** idea, since any attacker who manager to get the XML knows all of your accounts (and passwords!).

What I would expect, to keep the XML format:

- The client **POST**s instead of **GET**s to the server, and sends the username/password/email/any other data to the server
- The server does some checking, and responds with an XML, containing all the information required to do whatever it needs to. It also sets a cookie so that in the next requests, it knows to identify you.

  - If you want to do some simulation / testing, you can hardcode the server path to an XML file with a known result, eg POST to `assets/data/good.xml` or `assets/data/bad.xml`

If you actually need to have your accounts in a fetched XML document, at least hash the passwords, and check against the hash!

**PS:** Just noticed your request is to `../` -- are you sure that path is visible from the client? Most frameworks will ask you to point your webserver to the `public/` or `web/` directory, and expect that everything above that is not available to a client (needs to go through PHP or similar). If you enter the address you see on the browser, and append the `../assets/data/login.xml`, do you get a response?

Comment: Definitely a bad idea to send login data to client side. If a webserver is running (since it's just a college project) then as hexblot suggests the login data could be stored and validated on the server below docroot so it is not accessible.

Comment: Hi, as this is a college project for a clientside module, the security of this method doesn't matter, I just need to show my form validation, this form will never be used for anything. I am sure the login.xml path is correct, but I do not know how to do the Ajax call or request to implement this. Can anyone point me in the right direction, or to a tutorial that might be similar?